cordova-ios-7.1.0 still receiving Missing API declaration from apple
I am using cordova-ios-v7.1.0
The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file's target membership:

Even though I used the latest cordova ios version and supplied the necessary privacy declaration based on the initial email from apple, I am still receiving the same email for my current build. ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration...
Are there additional steps that need to be done?
Below are screen shots and code for reference.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>DDA9.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>E174.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
The above entries are generated from editing the same file on XCode UI
<platform name="ios">
   <privacy-manifest>
       <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
       <array>
           <dict>
               <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
               <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
               <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
               <array>
                   <string>DDA9.1</string>
               </array>
           </dict>
           <dict>
               <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
               <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
               <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
               <array>
                   <string>E174.1</string>
               </array>
           </dict>
           <dict>
               <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
               <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
               <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
               <array>
                   <string>CA92.1</string>
               </array>
           </dict>
       </array>
   </privacy-manifest>
   ......
</platform>

config.xml

Does this answer your question? cordova-ios 7.1.0 privacy-manifest correct format?

Unfortunaly no @tomerpacific, the entries you see on the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy code file is generated from editing it using XCode

I tried deleting then creating the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file, copied and pasted the generated content to config.xml then built and submitted the app. So far i have not received emails from Apple so far. Hopefully it will push through.
